# Android studio shows 'cannot resolve method/symbol'

Tags: android, android-studio

Almost everywhere it shows 'cannot resolve method/symbol' and compilation problems.
I'm new to Android Studio. Can anyone help me set it up?

Image with link:

[image: Click Here.]

Comment: Do you started your app from scratch?

Comment: yes, even tried re-installing it several times.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's gradle's fault. Go and click build from the top options, then select clean project.

Since I cannot see the rest of the code, I assume this is the problem.

Comment: Exactly what it says. Go to res/layout/activity_quiz.xml and check if the values that you used exists.

If that's not the problem, try changing your app's theme.

Comment: I may be wrong, but MainActivity.java shows all the errors.
Nothing changed with that.

Comment: Do you have the proper SDK installed?

Comment: Strange. It's not gradle, It's not the project... I guess this answer might not help you. But it might help someone else.